# How to resolve the Unterminated array Exception in android

Tags: java, android, json, android-webservice

```
    W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 12 of [ClassPojo [feed [{"id":0,"businessId":0,"businessName":"Farbinder","businessLogoUrl":"https:\/\/d1e6yi6s3cx2ur.cloudfront.net\/gallery\/0\/fb_icon.png","text":"Some news for yous!","photoUrl":"https:\/\/d1e6yi6s3cx2ur.cloudfront.net\/videos\/0\/8b84c9c1-50ed-4e93-9785797bbf2be667.png","videoUrl":"https:\/\/d1e6yi6s3cx2ur.cloudfront.net\/videos\/0\/_464b2fb6-ede6-403f-b6ae-1666c9504337.mov","isNew":true,"type":"news"},
{"id":198,"specialType":"limited","name":"Big Data Shoes!","description":"Get them now while you can. They're dangerous!","start":"2017-06-04 14:59:01Z","end":"2018-01-26 19:00:00Z","limitedAmount":30,"photoUrl":"https:\/\/d1e6yi6s3cx2ur.cloudfront.net\/specials\/77\/de050600-4aef-4f31-87c3-152ad4871fd4.jpeg","previewPhotoUrl":"https:\/\/d1e6yi6s3cx2ur.cloudfront.net\/specials\/77\/8878e285-8ac7-478d-aee5-73ad5fa2b861.jpeg.jpg","active":true,"expired":false,"totalClaimed":0,"totalShared":0,"businessName":"Big Data Shoes","businessId":77,"businessLogoUrl":"https:\/\/d1e6yi6s3cx2ur.cloudfront.net\/gallery\/0\/ph_logo.png","claimed":false,"redeemed":false,"isNew":false,
"shareInfo":{"title":"Big Data Shoes!","description":"Get them now while you can. They're dangerous!","photoUrl":"https:\/\/d1e6yi6s3cx2ur.cloudfront.net\/specials\/77\/de050600-4aef-4f31-87c3-152ad4871fd4.jpeg","linkUrl":"https:\/\/www.farbinder.com\/profile\/77","type":"share_info"},
"countInfo"{"views":171,"likes":0,"liked":false,"type":"count_info"},"type":"special"},
{"id":"1616636","partnerId":3,"uuid":"57dacc36-abac-4bb3-89a4-f1981130b206","title":"$80 Toward Gourmet Steakhouse Cuisine","category":"Restaurants > American","brand":"Regina's Steakhouse and Grill","imageUrl":"https:\/\/a1.lscdn.net\/imgs\/5605c229-0403-42db-a227-4720be82e29d\/360_q60.jpg","buyUrl":"https:\/\/m.livingsocial.com\/deals\/1616636-80-toward-gourmet-steakhouse-cuisine","price":"80.0 USD","salePrice":"40.0 USD","addr1":"827 Teaneck Road","city":"Teaneck","zip":"07666","type":"partner_offer"},
{"id":"b16cbffd-9162-105b-e342-511ce8e03e44","partnerId":5,"title":"Oil Change","category":"Automotive Oil Change \/ Car & Automotive","brand":"Valvoline Instant Oil Change - Galena Associates","imageUrl":"https:\/\/img.grouponcdn.com\/deal\/hzQxwQdyw5AJmR7PGf7Z\/qB-700x420\/v1\/t440x300.jpg","buyUrl":"http:\/\/tracking.groupon.com\/r?tsToken=US_AFF_0_206503_212556_0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.groupon.com%2Fdeals%2Fvalvoline-instant-oil-change-47-north-jersey%3Fz%3Dskip%26utm_medium%3Dafl%26utm_campaign%3D206503%26mediaId%3D212556%26utm_source%3DGPN","price":"$35.99","salePrice":"$19.99","addr1":"289 Dolson Avenue","city":"Middletown","type":"partner_offer"},
{"id":"1651220","partnerId":3,"uuid":"58da9c36-36cf-4979-aae6-76e02bf21445","title":"IPL Photo Facial ","category":"Health & Beauty > Spas ","brand":"The PRP Institute ","imageUrl":"https:\/\/a0.lscdn.net\/imgs\/58dc2906-bf3d-4d41-be14-c7a41431c19c\/360_q60.jpg","buyUrl":"https:\/\/m.livingsocial.com\/deals\/1651220-ipl-photo-facial","price":"250.0 USD","salePrice":"99.0 USD","addr1":"639 Teaneck Road","city":"Teaneck","zip":"07666","type":"partner_offer"},
{"id":"f267f724-d556-9903-04c4-a6c68eb25d53","partnerId":5,"title":"King Spa Fitness","category":"Bath - Steam \/ Spa Services","brand":"King Spa Fitness","imageUrl":"https:\/\/img.grouponcdn.com\/deal\/bBu8ESxBwUycrCnQDvCk\/22-700x420\/v1\/t440x300.jpg","buyUrl":"http:\/\/tracking.groupon.com\/r?tsToken=US_AFF_0_206503_212556_0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.groupon.com%2Fdeals%2Fking-spa-fitness-7-47%3Fz%3Dskip%26utm_medium%3Dafl%26utm_campaign%3D206503%26mediaId%3D212556%26utm_source%3DGPN","price":"$45.00","salePrice":"$26.50","addr1":"321 Commercial Ave.","city":"Palisades Park","type":"partner_offer"},
{"id":"1632898","partnerId":3,"uuid":"5849a6a8-1bd7-4848-ba0b-e12272f54d01","title":"$40 or $80 to Spend on Italian Cuisine","category":"Restaurants > American","brand":"Vitale's Restaurant","imageUrl":"https:\/\/a0.lscdn.net\/imgs\/584ad77e-3d2e-4b2a-8abe-8494ee6142fb\/360_q60.j
```

I want to parse this json response and design UI layouts.But it was throwing exceptions while parsing the data.Can any one help me how to resolve this issue.I observed that the last element in that response was breaking.I'm thinking that is the reason.

Comment: You can make pojo class with the help of pojo-generator to escape problems  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 1):

According this [Json lint tool](https://jsonlint.com/) your json content is incomplete.

[image]

Comment: How can I handle that. thats what I observed.@Victor Neves

Comment: Well if you just intend to avoid having your app crashed at this point, just catch this exception and keep things rolling.